Mid price for IRS SOFR
I’m trying to understand how market-makers derive the mid price for IRS SOFR swaps, particularly since there are no visible order books for these instruments (as far as I know).
From what I gather, market-makers typically start with a mid price from the market and adjust it based on their books, but how exactly is this mid price sourced?
I have a few hypotheses:
1 - Using ON-the-run (OTR) Treasury Bonds: One approach could be to take the mid price from OTR bonds on platforms like BrokerTec, build a discount curve from these instruments, and calculate the swap rate from that. However, since OTR bonds are not discounted using SOFR, this may introduce inaccuracies in the swap rate for SOFR swaps.
2- Using Recent Transactions: Another possibility is using the last transaction on a similar swap to set the price. The issue here is that TRACE data might only be available the following day, making it challenging to get timely information. Is there another source for real-time or near-real-time last traded prices for SOFR swaps?
3- Quoting SOFR Swaps as a Spread to OTR: I recall someone mentioning that SOFR swaps can be quoted as a spread to OTR Treasuries, but I haven’t found much detail about this on google (is it ICAP that operate these?). Are there order books for these swap spreads, or are they just indicative quotes that aren’t directly tradable? Additionally, how would market-makers determine a mid price for a swap tenor like 15 years, where there’s no OTR bond with a matching maturity?
Any insights or corrections on how this process works in practice would be much appreciated!

I would say MMs come up with a bid and and offer. I.e. where they pay and receive which can depend on many different variables. The mid is then derived from these prices. Mids are a theoretical construct, and typically you can't trade at mid
